# FOSUserBundle 2.0 no confirmation email after user registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and FOSUserBundle 2.0 and have overridden RegistrationControler to use my own User specification, but nothing different on the registration process.

When I set true to confirmation enabled no email is sent but working on reset password!

Here is my config.yml:

```
# FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
            form:
                type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
            confirmation:
                enabled: true
    profile:
            form:
                type: AppBundle\Form\ProfileType
```

Not sure what is happening, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

in yml files, tabs are not allowed, you need to use spaces only. And i'm sure you indent your "form" line too much.

```
registration:
    form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
profile:
    form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\ProfileType
```

Comment: Thanks but that's working fine, maybe copy-paste has change the yml format but the only problem I have is at confirmation email, is not sent but working perfectly at resseting password and many other mails I send from other controllers.

Comment: Could you show me your app.form.registration in your config/services.yml? And your RegistrationType.php?

Comment: I can not paste the code here ... but I'm only adding a few more fields, and registration works fine, I found in older versions that the problem was at an event in registration process in controller, ¿anybody has added something extending that controller?